# how to add textview and two buttons below textview in cardview xamarin

Tags: button, xamarin, textview, cardview

I have to add tetxview and two buttons inside cardview in such way that,
the two buttons should be on single line and below textview.
also please check below code for reference

here is my code

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"           
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
  card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
  card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp">
  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:textColor="#333333"
android:text="Caption"
android:id="@+id/textQuestion"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />              
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAnswer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Expalantion"
     />
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnVideo"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="video"
       />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you have set android:orientation="horizontal" for the LinearLayout. Make it vertical and then wrap two buttons in another LinearLayout which should be horizontal orientation. Check if its working.

Comment: thanks a lot. its working fine

Comment: Glad to know it worked!!